# Using multiple broadcast intents to control same thing

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

I want to enable/disable an alarm based on multiple intents broadcasted by the system, such as battery low, airplane mode enabled, wifi disabled.

I plan to register for the required intents in the manifest and consider them in a `BroadcastReceiver`, and set the alarm based on the received intents.

How can I best consider all conditions indicated by the registered intents at the same time, when only one of the intents is broadcasted?

For example: A "battery okay" intent is broadcasted, in which case I would normally enable the alarm again, but I don't want to enable it if airplane mode is on.

I was thinking about keeping the state of each condition updated in i.e. the shared preferences, but it doesn't seem like a clean solution at all.

Some intents are sticky so they can be obtained at any time, but since it is not possible to register for broadcast intents in a `BroadcastReceiver`, I can't seem to obtain the state of the other intents when one of them is sent.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question correctly,may be you are looking for this
You can register for multiple intents like this

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new Receiver(getApplicationContext());
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

and in recevier you can test what is now broadcasted like

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {


        }

        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) {
        }
```

Comment: In fact I found it difficult to explain my question... I know how to register for multiple events, but my question is, following your answer, what would be the best way to know i.e. the state of the battery at the moment an `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`intent is broadcasted?

Comment: You can know battery status at any time without broadcast receiver and actually you will get the previous broadcasted reading.But this is not true for other

Comment: Yes, it is what I meant with "some intents are sticky". Maybe I am able to use `PendingIntents` to retrieve the data of the original broadcast intents at a later time.